# Setting fronend attribute in Magento

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.9

I've recently been given an extension for 360 view images in Magento. Part of the extension adds a field to products in the backend which asks for a folder name. I'm attempting to write some code which will set this attribute for a large set of products. So far I have managed to read the attribute using the following code:

```
$productSKUs = array(102);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => $productSKUs) );

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $prouductInfo = $product->getAttributes();
    $objFolderName = $prouductInfo['imagecreator_obj_folder']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    echo $objFolderName;
}
```

However I can't find how to set the attribute to a new value.

If what I am trying to do is possible, any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you try : 

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setImagecreatorObjFolder('newValue')->save();
    //OR
    $product->setData('imagecreator_obj_folder','newValue')->save();
    // If this not work, try one more option, load product and then save its value which is demonstrated below
    $productData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $productData->setData('imagecreator_obj_folder','newValue')->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento ties the attributes tables to the product table through the magistery behind the EAV model, so the first thing to do is to get the product in the loop as you have been doing.

```
$product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

Then

```
$product->setData('imagecreator_obj_folder', 'newValue')->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'imagecreator_obj_folder');
```

You can insert this logic into the collection as you have done.